# Execute Maven/TestNG project using command line and DIFFERENT xml from command line?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have written a number of selenium tests using Maven and TestNG that are intended to be ran overnight via Jenkins.  However, it has been requested that I write some more specific tests that the QA team can run independently from Jenkins, with specific parameters (sku, etc).  Currently my automation tests are ran with maven, but how can I run them from the command line using the testing command, so it will run only run a specific file with command line options?  I tried this:

```
java -cp "/Users/kroe761/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.8/testng-6.8.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng2.xml
```

But I got this error (which I don't understand at all)

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

If there is a way to do this with `mvn test` then that would be even better, but I don't want to have modify the Jenkins job too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide suiteXmlFiles params case you're running your tests using surefire plugin, like described in [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)

When running from command line it should look like this:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=suite_location/suite.xml
```

Comment: That's super helpful.  I was hoping to have something like that, but is there any way to ALSO add in command line arguments that can be used in the code?  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, got it.  `-Dsku=123456` -> `System.out.println(System.getProperty("sku"));`. Thanks a lot for your help!